# How to set the value of Gender radio button while editing the form?

Tags: php, html

I have a Gender Row with radio buttons male & female. when i register as first time the values of radio button will store in database. Now my question is if I edit that row again it want to come(that means checked) with that value as male/female. how to make it?

Note : Doing with php.

HTML Script :

```
<label class="control-label" >Gender:</label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" >
        <label class="radio-inline"  >
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="optradio" checked>Male
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="optradio">Female
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make the correct (stored) gender to be checked when you repopulate the form?

Comment: If you are using plain PHP you have to make function e.g getGenderByName in which you pass the name and do for example  $sql = "Select from User where name = Namita;". Store the data into array
$result = $conn->query($sql); then var_dump($result) to see what fields you have there or simply type database field if you know name e.g echo $result['gender'];

Comment: To start with, have you checked that your db contains the correct value? You can't have the same `id` for two different elements. `id`'s must be unique + you're missing the `value` attribute on your radio buttons.

Answer (score 3):

```
<label class="control-label" >Gender:</label>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6" >
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" <?php if ($gender != "Female") echo "checked"; ?> />Male
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" <?php if ($gender == "Female") echo "checked"; ?> />Female
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some corrections I made:

- Self-closing input tags.
- Removed duplicate ids in your input tags
- Added values to your input tags.

Comment: This is one of those cases where a ternary operator actually makes it cleaner : `<?= $gender != 'Female' ? 'checked' : '' ?>`